# Do you know why are only appear 3 cards?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I want to have 4 cards in a row ,each card occupying the same width. But with the code below is not working. Only 3 cards are appearing. It seems that the issue is because there is a lot of margin between each card. Do you know how to properly solve this issue?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h82w46Lz/1/

HTML::

```
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the row div for the first four cards and add "col-lg-3" class instead of "col" and do the same for the second four cards.